# How to execute Update Mysql Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the method that makes update query to DB:

```
def update(url, status):
    try:

        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("""UPDATE apps SET status=%s WHERE id = 1""", (status))
        conn.commit()
        print("Updated: " + url)

    except:
        print("Update error: " + url)
```

It gives me exeption always.

The `conn` object is defined in another function, that is called firstly:

```
def connectDB():
    global cur
    global conn

    db = {
        'user': 'root',
        'password': '',
        'database': 'g'
    }

    """ Connect to MySQL database """
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                       database=db['database'],
                                       user=db['user'],
                                       password=db['password'])
        if conn.is_connected():
            pass


    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        print("MySQL Done...")
```

So, stack is:

```
connectDB();

for link in links:
   update(link, 1)
```

Comment: You should say what exception you get. You're hiding whatever it is by using a blank except; *don't* do that, let the exception display so that you can debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE apps SET status=%s WHERE id = 1""", (status))
```

the parameters should be passed to `cur.execute()` as a *tuple*. Adding parentheses around a single item is not a tuple, it's an expression. Try this instead:

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE apps SET status=%s WHERE id = 1""", (status,))
```

Here the `,` in `(status,)` makes all the difference; the argument is now a tuple.

Comment: But if I need to use `LIKE '% parameter %'` ?

Comment: Then it sholud be: `cur.execute("""UPDATE apps SET status=%s WHERE app_url LIKE '%%%s%%' """, (url, status,))` ?

Comment: I still get error exception: `insert = ("""insert into app (app_url) values ('%s')""", (url,))`

Comment: @MisterPi: I failed to read your mind :) And you would appear to have failed to read the documentation. What do you think is wrong with your insert query? When using parameterised queries you do not need to add the quotes for strings, the engine will do that for you. Try `cur.execute('insert into app (app_url) values (%s)', (url,))`. This of course assumes that other columns in your table will default to the correct values.

Comment: @MisterPi: regarding the use of LIKE you can do it by passing the `%` in the argument to `cur.execute()`: `cur.execute('UPDATE apps SET status=%s WHERE app_url LIKE %s', (status,'%{}%'.format(url)))`